# Как сделать мультивыбор списка?

Tags: php, html

Есть код выводящий дроп меню с выбором только одного из списка.

```
        $data = dbarray(dbquery("SELECT * FROM ".PREF."fields WHERE id=".$_GET['id']));
    echo "

        <div align='center'>
            <form name='form' action='?unit=fields&act=edit&id=".$_GET['id']."' method='post'>
            <FIELDSET style='width:500px;'><LEGEND>".$locale[399]."</LEGEND>
            <table width='100%' class='add_item'>
            <tr><td>".hlp($locale[383])." ".$locale[382]."</td><td><input id='name' name='name' type='text' value='".stripslashes($data['name'])."' style='width:100%;'></td></tr>
            <tr><td>".hlp($locale[385])." ".$locale[384]."</td><td><textarea name='comment' rows='3'  style='width:100%;' wrap='on'>".str_replace('<br />', "\n", stripslashes($data['comment']))."</textarea></td></tr>
            <tr><td>".hlp($locale[671])." ".$locale[17]."</td><td>
            <select size='1' name='cat'>
            <option value='0'>".$locale[449]."</option>
            ".make_select('cat', $cats_id, $data['cat'], $substr, ' / ')."
            </select>
```

Как сделать мультивыбор этого списка, либо чекбоксы?

Comment: В частности этот кусок:
            <select size='1' name='cat'>
            <option value='0'>".$locale[449]."</option>
            ".make_select('cat', $cats_id, $data['cat'], $substr, ' / ')."
            </select>

Answer (score 0):

```
<select size='1' name='cat[]' multiple>
```

[читать](http://htmlbook.ru/html/select/multiple)

Comment: пробовал такое, выводит, но при сохранении выбирает один

Comment: ... name ='cat[]'

Comment: Ругается на ошибку  strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string  А чекбоксы возможно сделать?

Comment: strip_tags() никак не относится к данным, переданным из select. Checkbox - можно конечно, #тыжпрограмист ;)

Comment: В том то и дело что php не дружу) иначе бы не спрашивал. Плиз хелп!

Comment: strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string - я так понимаю это в обработчике формы. Ранее вы передавали в $_POST['cat'] единственное строковое значение. Теперь туда прилетает массив. Соответственно, сперва обработайте сам массив cat. Например: implode("," $_POST['cat']);

Comment: что бы начать использовать checkbox, вам сперва необходимо переписать функцию make_select(), что бы она вам отдавала не option_list но checkbox_list